# Increasing/allocating RAM for ArcGIS usage?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, memory, hardware

In my x64 laptop I have 16G of RAM.
I see arcGIS is using 4G, I have 11G of RAM available.
Also, I was trying to process an 8G raster and I've got a not enough memory error.

Is there anyway I can make more RAM allocate/available for arcGIS usage?

Comment: Was the error specifically citing RAM and not disk memory? I only have 8G of RAM on one of my computers and have processed 100+G rasters. Make sure you have space to write the new image.

Comment: From my system info window: 15G RAM, 465G HardDrive1, 1000+G HardDrive2.

Comment: No software should ever need the full amount of RAM to access a large datafile.  The RAM required to read a raster shouldn't exceed the width times the tile height (times two if the format uses compression).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Although your Windows installation is 64-bit, ArcGIS Desktop is still 32-bit software and can't use more than 4GB of RAM in a single process. ***However***, you can install the ArcGIS [64-bit Background Geoprocessing](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/executing-tools/64bit-background.htm) addon, that will let you run most geoprocessing tools in 64-bit mode and they can use more than 4GB RAM in that case. There are some exceptions, but it doesn't look like they'll be a problem in your case:

> Tools that do not run in the background include the following:
>
> - Tools inside the Metadata conversion toolset
> - Tools inside the Geodatabase administration toolset
> - All Coverage tools Tools which create packages
> - Graphing tools (64-bit geoprocessing only; these tools
>   work in traditional 32-bit background processing)
> - Custom script, model, or function tools where the author has disabled background processing

Just install the 64-bit geoprocessing addon for your version of ArcGIS (you need to be running v10.1 or later) and enable background geoprocessing under the Geoprocessing > Geoprocessing Options menu.

Comment: Thanks Dan C, I'll install the addon, and I'll comment later.

Comment: Try ArcGIS Pro (As 64 bit application) http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/get-started/arcgis-pro-system-requirements.htm